# enable Virtualization via terminal

Tags: command-line, virtualization, bios

can I enable Intel Virtualization Technology via terminal or without using the bios. Is this possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

If it is disabled in BIOS you can not enable it in terminal. I had problem with my Lenovo laptop that did not have option for virtualization in BIOS and I had to update BIOS to get it enabled (I needed it for VirtualBox).

Comment: I have the same issue with my vaio because I cannot access advanced settings of bios, I want it for my virtual box too

Comment: Explain why cant you access these settings. My case was that the BIOS did not even display the AMD-V option.

Comment: To access the advanced settings I either have to press assist button and the power or f2 + power button but none of these works and I can only access bios but not the advanced settings. I have an e-series sony vaio

Comment: FWIW often advanced settings in the bios is disabled. You have to update the bios or if that fails write your own - https://www.bios-mods.com/

Comment: I looked on the net a bit and found a polite answer by some sony tech-guy that "users can only access basic BIOS. For more conntact sony services. "  I realy cant understand why!! If processor supports some feature why its disabled by laptop producer. Hope you find solution. Upgrading bios or something. Good luck.

Comment: Found these: http://www.techtangerine.com/2010/05/19/enabling-hardware-virtualization-on-a-sony-vaio-vgn-cr320-laptop-an-experience/